# I have a redirect error

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple login form and i have this redirect URL:

```html
<form method="post" action="/incs/login.php?redirect=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

but when I'm filling the form and hit the submit button I'm redirected to a wrong URL:

```
http://site/incs/login.php?redirect=/admin/index.php
```

which it's supposed to be like this:

```
http://site/admin/index.php
```

I'm following an old guide and I have looked for this (redirect) function on the internet but I could not find anything. Does this still work now or is it not supported any more?

Comment: Does your PHP actually attempt to *do* anything with that redirect variable? You can't just attach `?redirect=/path` to the end of the URL and expect it to work. What part actually handles the redirect?

Comment: Are you using a framework like yii or prado - please include a tag for that if you are

Comment: i have only found this: if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])){
 $url=preg_replace('/[\?\&].*/','',$_REQUEST['redirect']);
 if($url=='')$url='/';
}

Comment: no i'm not using any framework

Comment: You can't just set `redirect` in your variable and expect something to happen by itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to your URL does not do anything unless you actually use it in your server-side code. In your php script, you need to deal with the actual redirect, something like this:

```
<?php

/* Process form data */

if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])){
   $url = preg_replace('/[\?\&].*/','',$_REQUEST['redirect']);
   if ($url == '') $url='/';
}

header("Location: $url"); // <-- this is what actually redirects

?>
```

The above is a big simplification, but it shows the general idea. In a real application, you would probably only redirect if the form data was valid (a successful login, for example). You would probably also want to validate the redirect URL, to make sure that it's a valid URL in your site.

If you're using some kind of php framework, then it's going to handle all these details, and you just have to deal with configuring it properly.

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])){ $url=preg_replace('/[\?\&].*/','',$_REQUEST['redirect']); if($url=='')$url='/'; }

Comment: i found this above and i think that's exactly what you say, but where is the error?

Comment: There's no error, but that code doesn't perform a redirect, it just validates the redirect url. As I showed in my answer, you have to actually perform a redirect, not just set variables. I will edit to add your code.

Comment: To make an analogy, just using that code, and expecting the page to redirect would be like just stepping into your car, saying "I want to go to the store", and expecting it to magically drive there.

Comment: Yes thanks i understand, I'm looking for the redirection function now

Comment: I already posted it in my answer: [`header("Location: $url");`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: I think if I'm not wrong again i found it: function login_redirect($url,$msge='success'){
 if($msge)$url.='?login_msg='.$msge;
 header('Location: '.$url);
 echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'">redirect</a>';
 exit;
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15215/discussion-between-gordon-bailey-and-aram)